# What is the meaning/use of #geplant in an assignment?

Tags: variable-assignment, constants, x++

I'm just starting with X++ (Java background) and I found a code like

```
#XYZBatchScheduling
;
...
order.Status = #geplant;
```

`order` is a record to a table with a `Status` column.

My question: what is the meaning of `#USRBatchScheduling` and `#geplant` ("geplant" is "planned" in german) and eventually where to find it's definition.
I suppose it is some kind of constant but was unable to find `#` in the X++ reference (keywords).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#XYZBatchScheduling` is a [Macro library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197112.aspx). Look in the AOT under Macros for XYZBatchScheduling.

`#geplant` is a [Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197125.aspx), it is probably defined in the XYZBatchScheduling macro library, but it could be defined in several other places. It could be defined in the class declaration of the class the method is in, or if the class is a derived class, in the class declaration of any of the base classes. Look for a line that looks like:

```
#define.geplant(42)
```

Comment: thanks!! `Macro` was the magic word I needed! You're right about `#geplant`, it is defined in the macro library (not as 42 :--))